# Custom Angular 6 material table component with custom columns

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm trying to simplify creating tables with custom material table component where with very little code I can create a very custom table for each different data source with pagination and sorting already attached. All I have to pass is `displayedColumns` and `data`. Based on the examples [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/7.0.0-beta.0/src/demo-app/table/custom-table) I built this(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kp2ryv), but for some reason I'm getting error in StackBlitz when trying to use the custom column component.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Which tells me `@ViewChild(MatColumnDef) columnDef: MatColumnDef;` is not reading the `matColumnDef` in the template for some reason.

Example table creation with custom comp:

```
<dyn-table [data]="users" [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns">
    <dyn-col name="user_id"></dyn-col>
    <dyn-col name="user_name"></dyn-col>
</dyn-table>
```

Which would replace all this:

```
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table table-striped mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="user_id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User id </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">{{ data.user_id }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="user_name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">{{ data.user_name }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="10"></mat-paginator>
```

I've spent 2 days googling and trialing and erroring and I can't figure out why it's not reading it.

Working fork of the same StackBlitz but without custom column components https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jw9whh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that is that you defined NgModule with material directives from `@angular/material` module but now is trying to get access to directive from `@angular/material/table` module.

Just a small test:

```
import {MatColumnDef} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatColumnDef as RooColumnDef } from '@angular/material';

console.log(MatColumnDef, RooColumnDef, MatColumnDef === RooColumnDef);
                                                      ||
                                                     false
```

So as you can guess `MatTableModule` and `MatColumnDef` should be imported from the same module.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wm1psg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Oh wow. I had no idea that could even be the issue. I guess you learn something new everyday. How would you even start to figure that out? Thanks though.

Comment: I started with putting `debugger` inside `ViewChild` like `@ViewChild(MatColumnDef) set columnDef(val) { debugger }` And I had already known how `ViewChild` works under the hood.